# NestJs accept web socket on same path as http : ws://0.0.0.0:4001/{apiKey}

Tags: node.js, typescript, websocket, socket.io, nestjs

I have an HTTP post-API `http://0.0.0.0:4001/{apiKey}`.  I want to use the same for the web socket `ws://0.0.0.0:4001/{apiKey}` In NestJs `@WebSocketGateway({ path: '/:apiKey' })` expecting the same string provided as the path.

Does not work
`ws://0.0.0.0:4001/FGAFtrdsFSDS`

Works `ws://0.0.0.0:4001/:apiKey`

Adaptor

```js
import { MessageMappingProperties } from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Observable, EMPTY, fromEvent, mergeMap, filter } from 'rxjs';
import { WsAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-ws';

export class WsAdapterCustom extends WsAdapter {
  bindClientConnect(server, callback: any) {
    server.on('connection', (ws, req) => {
      const urlParts = req.url.split('/');
      const apiKey = urlParts.pop();
      console.log(`Connection URL: ${req.url}, API Key: ${apiKey}`);

      // Now you can use the apiKey as needed
      // For example, you can attach it to the WebSocket instance
      ws.apiKey = apiKey;

      // Call the original callback
      callback(ws);
    });
  }

  bindMessageHandler(
    buffer,
    handlers: MessageMappingProperties[],
    process: (data: any) => Observable<any>,
  ): Observable<any> {
    const { data, client } = buffer;
    console.log(`Client ${client} , ${data}`);

    const message = JSON.parse(buffer.data);

    const messageHandler = handlers.find(
      (handler) => handler.message === 'events',
    );
    console.log(messageHandler);

    if (!messageHandler) {
      return EMPTY;
    }
    return process(messageHandler.callback(message));
  }
}
```

Gateway

```js
const EXTERNAL_SERVER_URL = config.WS_URI;

@WebSocketGateway({ path: '/:apiKey' })
export class EventsGateway {
  private externalServerClient: WebSocket;

  constructor() {
    // Create a WebSocket client for the external server
    this.externalServerClient = new WebSocket(EXTERNAL_SERVER_URL);

    // Handle errors from the external server
    this.externalServerClient.on('error', (error) => {
      console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
    });
  }

  @SubscribeMessage('events')
  onHeartBeat(@MessageBody() data: any): Observable<any> {
    console.log('Here the data is without wrappers:', data);

    // Assuming data is an object with event and data properties

    // Send formatted data to the external server
    this.externalServerClient.send(JSON.stringify(data));

    // Return an observable that emits responses from the external server
    return new Observable((observer) => {
      // Handle messages from the external server
      this.externalServerClient.on('message', (response) => {
        try {
          const parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response.toString());
          observer.next(parsedResponse);
        } catch (error) {
          observer.error(error);
        }
      });

      // Handle errors from the external server
      this.externalServerClient.on('error', (error) => {
        observer.error(error);
      });

      // Handle the completion of the observable
      this.externalServerClient.on('close', () => {
        observer.complete();
      });
    });
  }
}
```